# java.lang.NumberFormatException: for input string {Date}. Spring MVC I cannot identify the error

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, crud

While working on a personal project I get a NumberFormatException. The error occurs while a form tries to display a Date variable as a string. The issue is that the set up is the same as another part of the project, where it is working just fine.

I am using two controllers one for different subsets of pages, which display and allow for manipulating different but related information. Like patients and their doctors.

This is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE bmi(
    bmi_id INT(14) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    date_weight DATE,
    height DECIMAL(5,2),
    weight DECIMAL(5,2),
    bmi DECIMAL(5,2),
    patient_id INT(11),
    PRIMARY KEY(bmi_id),
    CONSTRAINT wei_pat_fk FOREIGN KEY(patient_id) REFERENCES patient(patient_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB auto_increment=1 default charset=latin1;
```

This is the BMI object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table")
public class BMI {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="bmi_id")
    private int bmiId;

    @CreationTimestamp 
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="date_weight")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date createdW;

    @Column(name="weight")
    private BigDecimal weight;

    @Column(name="height")
    private BigDecimal height;

    @Column(name="bmi")
    private BigDecimal bmi;

    //Getter Setters
}
```

The Patient object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "patient")
public class Patient {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "patient_id")
    private int patientId;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull(message = "enter a date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "birth_date")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date birthDate;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "first_assesment")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date createdP;

    @Column(name = "sex")
    private String sex;

    @NotNull
    @Email
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH,
            CascadeType.DETACH })
    @JoinColumn(name="patient_id")
    private List<BMI> bmis;

//Getters Setters
}
```

This is the DAO object (The table in mySQL has a patient_id column):

```
@Repository
public class BMIImpl implements BMIDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sf;

...

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional
    public List<BMI> listBMIpat(int patId){
        Session s = this.sf.getCurrentSession();
        List<BMI> bmis = (List<BMI>) s.createSQLQuery("Select * from BMI B where B.patient_id = "+patId).list();
        return bmis;
    }
...
}
```

The service object:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class BMIServiceImpl implements BMIService {

    @Autowired
    private BMIDAO bdao;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<BMI> getBMIbyPatient(int patId) {
        return bdao.listBMIpat(patId);
    }
...
}
```

This is the controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/bmi/{patId}")
public class BMIController {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BMIController.class);

    public BMIController() {
        System.out.println("BMIController()");
    }

    @Autowired
    private BMIService bs;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView listBMIs(@PathVariable("patId") Integer patId, ModelAndView model) throws IOException {
        List<BMI> bmis = bs.getBMIbyPatient(patId);
        model.addObject("listBMIs", bmis);
        model.setViewName("viewBMIs");
        return model;
    }
...
}
```

This is the page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <...>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Created</th>
                <th>Weight</th>
                <th>Height</th>
                <th>BMI</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            <tr>
                <c:forEach var="bmi" items="${listBMIs}">
                    <tr>
                        <td><fmt:formatDate pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" value="${bmi.createdW}" /></td>
                        <td>${bmi.weight}</td>
                        <td>${bmi.height}</td>
                        <td>${bmi.bmi}</td>
                        <td><a href="editBMI?bmiId=${bmi.bmiId}">Edit</a> <a
                            href="deleteBMI?bmiId=${bmi.bmiId}">Delete</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The Error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "createdW"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.coerce(ArrayELResolver.java:144)
    at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getValue(ArrayELResolver.java:61)
    at org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:110)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:190)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:944)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.viewBMIs_jsp._jspx_meth_fmt_005fformatDate_005f0(viewBMIs_jsp.java:254)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.viewBMIs_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(viewBMIs_jsp.java:198)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.viewBMIs_jsp._jspService(viewBMIs_jsp.java:150)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Oct 11, 2019 5:36:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/LymphodemaProjectMVC] threw exception [java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "createdW"] with root cause
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "createdW"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.coerce(ArrayELResolver.java:144)
    at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getValue(ArrayELResolver.java:61)
    at org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:110)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:190)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:944)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.viewBMIs_jsp._jspx_meth_fmt_005fformatDate_005f0(viewBMIs_jsp.java:254)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.viewBMIs_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(viewBMIs_jsp.java:198)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.viewBMIs_jsp._jspService(viewBMIs_jsp.java:150)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have the exact same set up for the patients table but I get no Exception messages when I run that part of the project.

Edit:
I delete the information inside the table in mySQL and now the page loads properly. I have no idea why that is though.

Edit:
I found that the date is being stored differently on the database. While, it is stored in one format for patients, for bmi is sotred in a different format. This means when it tries loading the date, it does not see it as a date and gives the error. I have no idea why that is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crux of the problem lies with this part:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional
    public List<BMI> listBMIpat(int patId){
        Session s = this.sf.getCurrentSession();
        List<BMI> bmis = (List<BMI>) s.createSQLQuery("Select * from BMI B where patient_id = "+patId).list();
        return bmis;
    }
```

`s.createSQLQuery()` was returning the result of the query as a text. Changed it to `sf.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from BMI B where B.patientId = "+patId).list();`and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you added this line at the top of the page.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```

Comment: Yes, I modified the initial comment, but the taglib is there.